# What is the general solution to $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Can anyone help explain to me what the general solution is to this? As I understand it is not the same as dealing with PDE's as $f$ is a function of $z=x+iy$ so is probably not $f=g(z)+h(\bar{z})$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right)=0$$

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: You may identify that $$ \Delta f = 4 \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial z \partial \bar{z}},$$ so that the equation in question reduces to the Laplace equation. Then the solutions are (by definition) harmonic functions.

Comment: An extra note to @sos440's comment: if you write $x=(z+\bar{z})/2$ and $y=(z-\bar{z})/(2i)$ and use the chain rule, the relationship between your operator and the Laplacian should become clear.

Comment: @sos440: Thanks very much, and so to Chris Taylor, that was me being slow

Comment: @sos440: So I see that is reduces to laplaces equation, but how do you go about solving that with a complex function?

Comment: could you say that this means that $u_{xx}+u_{yy}+i(v_{xx}+v_{yy})=0$, then solve for $u,v$ normally?

Comment: Dear @sos440: I suggest that you upgrade your comment to an answer. (I voted for the comment, and will vote for the answer.) [You were the first one to answer, and now everybody is repeating what you wrote!]

Comment: It is a map with two independent real compenents, each of which is harmonic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your differential equation is solved by any holomorphic function.

In fact, call $w=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ and your equation rewrites $\frac{\partial w}{\partial \bar{z}}=0$; hence, if the domain of $f$ (and of $w$, of course) is a simply connected open set, $w$ is a holomorphic function; but then also $f$ is holomorphic (for it is an antiderivative of $w$).

On the other hand, is $f$ is holomorphic in a simply connected open set, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} =f^\prime$ is also holomorphic there; therefore $\frac{\partial f^\prime}{\partial \bar{z}} =0$.

Comment: yes, but that's not the general solution.